# react-intl FormattedDate Shows Prior Date for YYYY-MM-DD value

Tags: react-intl

Please note I'm new to react-intl.  I have the following date I want to display:

> d1_date: "2012-03-26" //goal to display March 26, 2012

I use react-intl's

> FormattedDate

to display the date:

```
<FormattedDate value={d1_date} year='numeric' month='long' day='2-digit' />
```

and I get the following result:

> March 25, 2012

I know the d1_date doesn't have time information.  Do I need to manipulate d1_date so that a bogus time appears allowing the true date to reflect "March 26, 2012"?

Comment: The shift in the day is coming about due to the browser's timezone. I've yet to fix this issue myself. I'd like to use the localisation of FormatterDate but force the timezone to that of our application. Chrome is fixed by doing the following: `<FormattedDate value={new Date(date + ' 00:00:00')}...`, but this fails on other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<FormattedDate value={new Date('2012-03-26')} year='numeric' month='long' day='2-digit' />
```

I think it requires Date instance.